# Es correcto usar un iframe o un div con AJAX

Tags: html

Hola soy novato en programación y yo se que me falta un gran camino para aprender pero tengo una duda es correcto usar un inframe para mostrar otro sitio en un sitio o usar div y ajax (que desconozco un poco) para mostrar un sitio en un div?

Disculpa por mi ignorancia

Comment: Eso depende completamente de tu caso de uso, Si puedes elaborar más que es la meta de mostrar una pagina externa en tu pagina, es más fácil de explicarte las ventajas y problemas de ambos métodos.

Comment: Son cosas diferentes que no tienen relación entre sí. AJAX es una petición asíncrona hacia un endpoint, sea un controlador, una API, etc. La idea de usar ésta técnica se debe a varios factores, entre ellos, una mejor UX (user experience) y un mejor aprovechamiento del ancho de banda. Un `iframe` es simplemente una característica de HTML que te permite incrustar una página HTML dentro de otra. ¿Cuándo es útil? Por ejemplo cuando quieres darle acceso a tus usuarios a cierto sitio sin que salgan del tuyo, etc. Debes entender primero para qué sirve cada cosa para entender todo el conjunto.

Comment: me alegra percibir que andas con sed de aprendizaje :D aquí tienes unos enlaces para que te abran la mente en este mundo de la programación: http://www.freecodecamp.com/ - http://mva.microsoft.com/ - https://developer.mozilla.org/ - http://tutorialspoint.com/ y si el idioma inglés deseas dominar: https://www.duolingo.com/ - https://www.memrise.com/ ahora depende más de organizar el tiempo y hacer las cosas, ahora puedes iniciar pagando solo con tiempo, dedicación, esfuerzo y no con dinero (hay cursos pagados que valen la inversión) saludos y éxitos con el desarrollo de software!